# apt-get not finding valid package to install

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, ppa

I installed the following PPA:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu/ xenial main
```

performed an update but apt-get is unable to find a package that is listed. If you check here,

https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=xenial

you'll see a number of nvidia-graphics-drivers-xyz available for xenial. However, apt-get doesn't recognize them at all.

Here is some information showing the state of my machine,

```
(base) joehays@scylla:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]                              
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]                                      
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                        
Hit:6 https://xpra.org xenial InRelease                                            
Fetched 325 kB in 0s (417 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
(base) joehays@scylla:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-430
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-430
(base) joehays@scylla:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ inxi -r
Repos:     Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list
           deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
           deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
           deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
           deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
           deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
           deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
           deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
           deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
           deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
           deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
           deb https://xpra.org/ xenial main
           Active apt sources in file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
           deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu/ xenial main
(base) joehays@scylla:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$
```

I'm suring that I'm missing something simple and obvious but I'm missing it. Packages are listed on the PPA website for xenial. I have the PPA installed and performed an update yet it's not finding the package.

I've looked at related posts but have not found a solution...

Anybody see the obvious that I'm missing?

[UPDATE]OS version information:

```
joehays@scylla:/etc$ cat os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Why do you have "(base) "? Is it a chroot or conda environment?

Comment: @N0rbert, yes, "(base)" is the active python virtual environment. It's irrelevant. I just deactivated it and reupdated and the problem persists. I've also updated the post with my OS version information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the following - the `nvidia-graphics-drivers-430` is the name of source package, but the main binary is named simply `nvidia-430` - check [this page on PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=nvidia-graphics-drivers-430&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=xenial).

So you can use command below to install Nvidia 430:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-430
```

or install them using GUI from 5th tab of *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`) named *Addtional Drivers*.